# Can not find js.map file?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a wordpress install and am working on building out a custom theme. But for some reason I keep getting a console 404 error saying that the [path to file]/waves.min.js.map is not found. I do not have a waves.js.map file nor do I kno what a .js.map file is.

The effect is still working and I am not having any issues related to the file. Can anyone tell me what would cause a .js.map or what it is or even how to make one?

Comment: If you check the console you can see the line where the script is in the HTML. With that information you can check the theme's files or the plugins you might be using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This file is known as source maps you can read more about it [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/), you can disable this behavior by removing line `//@ sourceMappingURL=PATH_TO_waves.js.map` from waves.js if waves.js doesn't come with this file.